# MS Project 2016 export to excel stored in Sharepoint online not replacing file

Tags: sharepoint-online, ms-project

When trying to export a .mpp file to an Excel workbook, overwriting an existing file stored in a sharepoint online document library, the export wizard completes all the necessary steps and completes successfully without any warning being issued.

When opening the file on SharePoint online the file has not been updated/replaced.

The file should have been replaced with the latest version but did not occur.

I also tried to create a new export file and no file was created.

When saving to a local file the file is replaced correctly.

Can any one advise if there is a way to make it work or else an alternative.

The exports are to be used for collating into Power BI.

Comment: user..... Two issues. First, since your question is not about programming Project (e.g. VBA) it should be posted to the project management section of stackexchange at - https://pm.stackexchange.com. Second, you don't mention how you performed the export. That could be relevant.

Comment: Since this question is more related to Project, please start a new discussion via the Project Community so that you can get dedicated support on this issue. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/project/ct-p/Project